# Function to Withdraw amount from an array of balance

Tags: c++, function, loops, if-statement

I'm to write a function to withdraw money from array containing initial balance.

> If the balance is insufficient, then a warning message along with user's balance is displayed.
>
> The user is prompted to enter the new amount for a second time, if the amount is OK withdraw operation is completed and balance is updated and menu is displayed.
>
> If balance is still insufficient, withdraw operation is terminated and menu is displayed.

Below is the code which works if I try to enter amount which is lower than the balance for the first time. But does not update the balance well if I enter the valid amount on the second try.

```cpp
double withdrawAmount(int pin, double balance[]){
    double amount;
    double newBalance = balance[pin];
    int withdrawTrial = 0;
    do{
        system("cls");
        cout << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "\tWELCOME TO EDON ATM" << endl;
        cout << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter amount to be withdrawn: $";
        cin >> amount;
        if (balance[pin] < amount){
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Insufficient Balance!" << endl;
            cout << "Your balance is: $" << balance[pin] << endl;
            cout << endl;
            while (withdrawTrial < 1){
                withdrawTrial++;
                cout << "Please enter amount to be withdrawn: $";
                cin >> amount;
            }
            if (withdrawTrial == 1){
                menuBoard();
                return newBalance;
            }
        }
        balance[pin] -= amount;
        newBalance = balance[pin];
    } while (amount < 0);
    return newBalance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not following the instructions correctly. You are not validating the user's input on the second prompt. Get rid of the `while (withdrawTrial < 1)` loop completely. Prompt once and validate.  If the `amount` is greater than the available `balance` then prompt again and re-validate.  If the `amount` is still greater than the available `balance` then exit.  No loops are needed (unless you want to validate the user is actually entering a floating-point number and nothing else).

Also, you should not be calling `menuBoard()` inside of `withdrawAmount()` itself, you should be calling it after `withdrawAmount()` exits.

```cpp
double inputDollars(const char *prompt){
    double value;

    do {
        cout << prompt << ": $";
        if (cin >> value)
            break;

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Invalid Input!" << endl;

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    while (true);

    return value;
}

double withdrawAmount(int pin, double balance[]){
    double amount;

    system("cls");
    cout << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\tWELCOME TO EDON ATM" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    amount = inputDollars("Please enter amount to be withdrawn");

    if (balance[pin] < amount){
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Insufficient Balance!" << endl;
        cout << "Your balance is: $" << balance[pin] << endl;
        cout << endl;
        amount = inputDollars("Please enter amount to be withdrawn");

        if (balance[pin] < amount){
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Insufficient Balance!" << endl;
            return balance[pin];
        }
    }

    balance[pin] -= amount;

    return balance[pin];
}

...

double balances[N];
int pin;
...

withdrawAmount(pin, balances);
menuBoard();
```